# Login to wordpress website using an existing google

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site.
currently I don't have any login/registration page/form in our website.
I need to create a login page where user can login using an existing google account. it should be the only way to login to our website. Please note, I'm not talking about login page to wordpress admin pages...I'm talking about login page for website.
Steps:
1) user goes to my website
2) click login link
3) navigates to goole sign in page
4) sign in
5) back to the website , the user is logged in

Is there any WP plugin for such case.

TIA, Anna

Comment: So you want the user to be able to comment with their google account?

Comment: What exactly are they logging in to?

Comment: They should log in to my website in order to comment with their google account. Now users have to set their name and email in order to submit a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that the login page for the WP admin pages *is* the default login screen for users as WP understands them. I don't know what you expect logged-in users to be able to do or see, but you'd have to manage that access at a different level if you're not using the WP users.

If you just want commenting but with Google logins (and others) I'd recommend [Disqus](http://disqus.com).

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign up with Google for this: https://developers.google.com/accounts/ There are several options there like using Google+ log-in, etc.

I haven't seen a wordpress plug-in for it, and even if there is, you'd probably have to register with Google somewhere in the above link because they need to give your specific website permission.

If you want to cut to the chase, look at this link which talks about installing the google button using HTML https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button